# Em versus px settings for fluid layouts

Tags: css, font-size

Im reading about optimal font sizing and layout sizing...and Im looking into em instead of px.

From what I understand, if I make the css like this;

```
html {
font-size: 16px;
}

body {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

It will force the browser to make 16px = 1em, and that will enable me to do width and height properties by calculating desired pixels/16, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all browsers gave their default font size as 16px.

So if you simply set font-size:100% on your body tag then work from that you'll be golden.

Here's a good site that I use for calculating font-sizes from your base size:

http://riddle.pl/emcalc/

In the settings tabs simply change it to 16px and that's you set.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, and so is @Billy Moat.

You're not really gaining anything by explicitly declaring the 16px value on the HTML element - browsers tend to do that anyway.

Another trick that you can use is the "62.5%" trick.

If you declare:

```
body { font-size: 62.5% }
```

You can make further declarations in em's that map neatly to pixel measurements. e.g.:

```
h1 { font-size: 3em; /* equals 30px */ }
h2 { font-size: 2.4em; /* equals 24px */ }
.nav { width: 50.5em /* equals 505px */ }
```

That's because 10/16 = .625. So with this trick, you can rebase your measurements and not have to do the math later of dealing with a 16px base.

The only trick of this method is that once you declare a font size for an element, all children elements have to have their em values based on that parent's value (this is true of all relative units of measurement).